# Nextflow join file to tuple

Tags: nextflow

I have problem with nextflow, I have a tuple with 3 elements (id, fastq_File, out_file) and I need join a new file to every tuple element (same file for all tuple element).

Well first I have a fastq, and I split this in chunks, and map with their id, after I have a process (simple process in the example), but this process return the id with other file.

```
reads = Channel.fromPath( 'data/illumina.fastq' )
.splitFastq(by: 150_000, file:true)

 reads.map { it -> [it.name -  ~/\.fastq/, it] }
            .into{tuple_reads ; tuple_reads2}

process pr1 { /*is an example my real process is more complex*/
echo true

input:
tuple val(id), path(file) from tuple_reads

output:
tuple val(id),  file("example${id}.out") into example_test

script:
"""
echo example${id} > example${id}.out
"""
}

readss = tuple_reads2.join(example_test)
```

I join the channels and I obtain something like this:

```
[illumina.1, /home/qs/work/../illumina.1.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.1.out]
[illumina.2, /home/qs/work/../illumina.2.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.2.out]
[illumina.3, /home/qs/work/../illumina.3.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.3.out]
```

Now, I have a channel with my id, the fastq file, and the out from process pr1, perfect for me, but this is the problem now, I need to create other process to run with a static file.
I need that every id run with the static_file but I don't know how do this. I need a new channel with something like this:

```
[illumina.1, /home/qs/work/../illumina.1.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.1.out,/home/qs/work/../static_file.txt]
[illumina.2, /home/qs/work/../illumina.2.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.2.out,/home/qs/work/../static_file.txt]
[illumina.3, /home/qs/work/../illumina.3.fastq, /home/qs/work/../exampleillumina.3.out,/home/qs/work/../static_file.txt]
```

or I need a process that repet the static file with every run.
The below code only run with the first element from the tuple :( (I tried with each but doesn't work.

```
process pr2 {
echo true

input:
  tuple val(id), path(fastq_file), path(out_file) from example_test
  path(st_file) from static_file

script:
"""
echo ${id} ${st_file}
"""
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure your second channel (i.e. the one for your static file) is a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). You didn't show how the static_file channel came was created, but you'll get the behaviour you're seeing if it's a regular queue channel, see here: [Understand how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work). To fix your example, all you need is:

```
static_file = file(params.static)

process pr2 {

    echo true

    input:
    tuple val(id), path(fastq_file), path(out_file) from example_test
    path(st_file) from static_file

    script:
    """
    echo ${id} ${st_file}
    """
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
static_file = file(params.static)

process pr2 {

    echo true

    input:
    tuple val(id), path(fastq_file), path(out_file) from example_test
    path static_file

    script:
    """
    echo ${id} ${static_file}
    """
}
```